# basic authentication in android

Tags: android

does this https://webmail.ibs-b.hu/owa/ url uses .htaccess authentication? 
if yes how can I authenticate with it in android?

is there any implemented method in httprequest?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it uses HTTP based NTLM authentication: http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html

There is no out of the box solution for Http NTLM auth on Android. But since this is all HTTP you can use HttpClient to handle it: http://danhounshell.com/blog/android-using-ntlm-authentication-with-httpclient/